# Startup a remote WildFly Server, and deploying to it

Tags: eclipse, deployment, startup, remote-server, wildfly

I would like to setup another machine as a deployment machine for my web project. Currently my setup is that I have WildFly on my own machine, and I start it up via eclipse (Keplar). I have an existing wildFly Server setup, that I just copied, and made changes to connect to a remote machine.

I have copied WildFly to the same directory structure on the new machine, and I then add a new server on my own machine in eclipse, specifying the machine name. It says SSL is not properly setup on the new machine, but I just ignore that, since a tutorial I followed says I can (http://www.mastertheboss.com/eclipse/jboss-tools/deploy-applications-to-a-remote-wildfly-server-using-eclipse).

It seems that the new host machine is not setup properly, because I cannot see any files from the "browse remote host" option on the Server Behaviour tab.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks.